# CKEditor 4 как попало оборачивает в тэг <p>

Tags: ckeditor

Делаю такую вставку кода для последющей обработки

```
<div class="row">@include('widget', ['id'=>60])</div>
```

редактор подменяет на

```
<div class="row"><p>@include('widget', ['id'=>60])</p></div>
```

Как это отключить ?

Аналогичная проблема при вставке списков. Хочу так:

```
<ul>
    <li>item-1</li>
    <li>item-2</li>
    <li>item-3</li>
</ul>
```

Редактор превращает это в:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <p>item-1</p>
    </li>
    <li>item-2</li>
    <li>item-3</li>
</ul>
```

Т.е. оборачивается только один из элементов списка.
Как исключить оборачивание? Мне в списке не нужен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Часть проблемы удалось решить такой настройкой.

```
config.protectedSource.push( /<li[\s\S]*?\>/g ); 
config.protectedSource.push( /<\/li[\s\S]*?\>/g );
```

Теперь `<p>` не появляется внутри `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

В конфигурации добавьте эту строку:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config)
{
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;

    ...
};
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложение. Потестил. Это не совсем то. Эта настройка вместо <p> вставляет <br> при нажатии на вовод. Проблема в другом. Я не хотел отказаться от использования параграфов при нажатии ввода.